# KO: two variables subscribing to each other

Tags: knockout.js

I do not know how to formulate that question correctly...
I want to have two variables that are watching each other and changing accordingly. One is decimal another is percentage.

I have one observable in my model. It gets value from server side.

```
self.varDecimal = ko.observable(valueFromServerSide);
```

This variable holds decimal value. What I need is to show this variable in input box (actually it would be touchspin with custom binding) and allow user to edit it. However, I need user to edit not decimal value, but percentages.

```
self.varPercents = ko.observable(); //should be = self.varDecimal * 100
```

So:

1) when data are mapped from server, I need `self.varPercents` to be computed from `self.varDecimal` (`self.varDecimal() * 100`).

2) I need `self.varPercents` to be shown in input (actually it would be touchspin, but this is later) and user is allowed to edit percentages.

3) User is editing this percentage and I want `self.varDecimal` to update accordingly `(self.varPercents / 100)`. Later self.varDecimal is send back to server.

Is it possible with some KO subscriptions or computes or similar way?

I know I can live without it, for example, when receiving data I can simply calculate self.varPercents, but when sending data back to server I can recalculate self.varDecimal, but I would like to know if this is possible via some knockout features, because in reality I have many fields like this and I want some generic sollution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a writable computed

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#writeable-computed-observables

http://jsfiddle.net/QAe72/

```
this.percentage = ko.computed({
    write: function(value) {            
       this.decimal(value / 100);
    },
    read: function() {
        return this.decimal() * 100;
    }
}, this);
```